# non-finite function value with integrate() when use function 'nlminb'

Tags: r

My purpose is to find out the optimal parameters.

First, I have the function "func" which produces the results with 5 parameters.
Second,I use R's function 'nlminb' to find out the optimal parameters.
The function "func" seems OK. But I get the error message after running 'nlminb' and the message is: integrate(function(u)) {:non-finite function value}.
The integration is a part of function "func". If it has mistake, the function "func" should not work.However, it works fine. So I don't understand where is the mistake.

```
func<- function(params){

lambda<-params[1]
rho<-params[2]
eta<-params[3]
vbar<-params[4]
v<-params[5]

res <- function(k,t){
fj <- function(u, t, j){
  al <- -exp(log(u)+log(u))*(1/2) - exp(log(1i)+log(u))*(1/2) + exp(log(1i)+log(u))*j;
  bet <- lambda - rho*eta*exp(log(1i)+log(u))-rho*eta*j;
  gam <- eta^2/2;
  d <- sqrt(bet*bet - 4*al*gam);
  rp <- (bet + d)/(2*gam);
  rm <- (bet - d)/(2*gam);
  g <- rm / rp;
  D <- rm * (1 - exp(-d*t))/ (1 - g*exp(-d*t));
  C <- lambda * (rm * t - 2/eta^2 * log( (1 - g*exp(-(d*t)))/(1 - g) ) );
  return(exp(C*vbar + D*v));} 
x <- -k;
p1 <- 1/2+1/pi*integrate(function(u){Re(fj(u,t,1)*exp(1i*u*x)/(1i*u))},lower=0,upper=Inf,stop.on.error=FALSE)$value;
p0 <- 1/2+1/pi*integrate(function(u){Re(fj(u,t,0)*exp(1i*u*x)/(1i*u))},lower=0,upper=Inf,stop.on.error=FALSE)$value;
return(exp(k)*(exp(x)*p1-p0));
}
return(res);
}
```

my initial parameters are

```
 params<-c(1.15,-0.64,0.39,0.04,0.04)
```

In order to run function 'nlminb', I should also define objective function, upper and lower boundaries:

```
 lower<-c(0,-1,0,0,0)
 upper<-c(10,1,1,1,5)
```

The objective function is

```
 obj<-function(params)
 {
  re<-NULL
  for(i in 1:length(k))
  {re[i]<-func(params)(k[i],myExpiry[i])*2072-resDF$Mid[i]}
  return(sum(re^2))
  }
```

k, myExpiry and resDF$Mid are imported data.
The last step is to run 'nlminb':

```
 nlminb(start=params,objective = obj,lower=lower,upper=upper)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!